# bash script command not found

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to run bash script written in here: [Link](http://dryize.wordpress.com/2014/04/02/protected-hls-using-ffmpeg-and-openssl/)

I fixed script above like this:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

keyFile=video.key
openssl rand 16 > $keyFile
encryptionKey=cat $keyFile | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"'

splitFilePrefix=stream
encryptedSplitFilePrefix=enc/${splitFilePrefix}

numberOfTsFiles=ls ${splitFilePrefix}*.ts | wc -l

for (( i=1; i<$numberOfTsFiles; i++ ))
 do
 initializationVector=printf '%032x' $i
 openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in ${splitFilePrefix}$i.ts -out ${encryptedSplitFilePrefix}$i.ts -nosalt -iv $initializationVector -K $encryptionKey
```

---

ran script like this: `./script.sh`

but bash keeps yelling like this:

```
./script.sh: line 5: video.key: command not found

./script.sh: line 10: stream0.ts: command not found
0

./script.sh: line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have no idea why..

I searched about the error and checked `~/.rnd owner`, `.sh file chmod +x`, `$PATH` problems, but all of them did not work.

Comment: You are missing some characters in your script, in the original, line 5 is for example like this: `keyFile=”video.key”`, line 10: should be like this: `splitFilePrefix=”stream”` etc. Pls check the original script again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
encryptionKey=cat $keyFile | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"'
```

is trying to execute `cat`, but you are not using [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). It should be:

```
encryptionKey=$(cat "$keyFile" | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"')
```

similarly, you need:

```
numberOfTsFiles=$(ls ${splitFilePrefix}*.ts | wc -l)
```

and need a done after the loop:

```
for (( i=1; i<$numberOfTsFiles; i++ ))
do
   # ...
done
```